# Fixing rtl bootstrap navbar dir

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using the following code as navbar, and starts well from the right side, however the sorting of the menus is `ltr` and it should be `rtl`, meaning "Dropdown 1" starts from the right side of the page.. etc.

It shows as:

[image]

And it should be:

[image]

- I tried adding `float: right` but it is already implemented in the bootstrap css, and also `dir="rtl"` in the html/body/divs.. but no luck.
- Also I would like to now which `@media` option in the css that makes the menu invisible with smaller screens, as IUI tried to add `@media (min-width: 200px !important)` as a css, but still the menu gets hidden in smaller frames (I think from bootstrap.min.css file: `@media (min-width: 768px)`).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap Dropdown Hover</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap Dropdown Hover CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/assets/bootstrap-dropdownhover/css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/assets/bootstrap-dropdownhover/css/bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.css">



  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="bs-demo-showcase">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-material-blue navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">


          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-animations" data-hover="dropdown" data-animations="fadeInDownNew fadeInRightNew fadeInUpNew fadeInLeftNew">
            
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 3<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 4<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>


            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>


      </div>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/assets/bootstrap-dropdownhover/js/bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

P.S. the above snippet will work well by showing the code in "Full page" option, or through jsfiddle (enlarging the results frame): https://jsfiddle.net/gtfmbc54/1/

Comment: you want all the dropdowns to start from left?

Comment: Yes.  I updated the question with an example.

Comment: i overrided the css with !important so your saying even if we fixed it with float:left !important  it wont work on mobile?

Comment: The `@media` is another question, and yes it didn't change.  Try to add in the css section here and tell me if it works: https://jsfiddle.net/gtfmbc54/1/

Comment: for me it works and i found it to show on mobile size

Comment: Send me the link of the edited script please so I can check.

Comment: ill give you the two css to add and tell me if its good

Comment: ive added the code in the answer hope it helps

Comment: i edited my answer plz check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i overrided the css

```css
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: right!important;
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse{display: block!important;
  height: auto!important;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  overflow: visible!important;
  visibility: visible!important;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap Dropdown Hover</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap Dropdown Hover CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/assets/bootstrap-dropdownhover/css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/assets/bootstrap-dropdownhover/css/bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.css">



  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="bs-demo-showcase">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-material-blue navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">


          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-animations" data-hover="dropdown" data-animations="fadeInDownNew fadeInRightNew fadeInUpNew fadeInLeftNew">
            
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 3<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 4<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Another dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>


            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>


      </div>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://kybarg.github.io/bootstrap-dropdown-hover/assets/bootstrap-dropdownhover/js/bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your css file

```
.nav {
  direction: rtl;
  display: flex;
}

.caret {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hosam, I changed the `<div class="bs-demo-showcase>` and added what you suggested but it didn't change it.  Try to edit the jsfiddle here to see the change in real-time and tell me: https://jsfiddle.net/gtfmbc54/1/

Comment: you want dropdown buttons to be on the left side or you mean the menu that popup that start from left to right?

Comment: i've saved the fiddle and edited it with my answer go check it

Comment: Send me the link please.  I also added an example of what needed to be done as images in the question.

Comment: sorry now you can take a look at the answer I've changed it